# Faster base conversion algorithm

Tags: algorithms

In [Modern Computer Arithmetic](http://www.loria.fr/~zimmerma/mca/mca-cup-0.5.9.pdf) comes with Algorithm 1.26 FastIntegerOutput a reference to Exercise 1.35 where one should show how to speed up the algorithm using [Bernstein’s scaled remainder tree](http://cr.yp.to/arith/scaledmod-20040820.pdf) and middle product. Looks like the idea should be to replace some divisions with multiplications. But I can't connect the dots.

Can anyone show me the path? Can't see how to put the remainder tree and middle product together and use it in FastIntegerOutput Algorithm. Can it be done only with integer/modular arithmetic (since the scaled remainder tree looks to require floating-point arithmetic)?

Is there any faster division algorithm than Algorithm 1.8 RecursiveDivRem computed only by means of integer/modular arithmetic?